# FCKEditor replaces & with &amp; when switching from source to design view?

Tags: wordpress, special-characters, fckeditor

I have the problem that my installed FCKEditor 3.3.1 changes all `&` to `&amp;`.

I am posting lots of links in my posts and this makes them invalid. Where can I define that `&` ist NOT replaced with `&amp;`?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. FCKEditor does the right thing.

There is no situation where a standalone `&` in HTML is *not* an error. The ampersand *always* has to be encoded as `&amp;` - unless it is the start of an escape sequence itself (like in `&lt;`).

It is a misconception that the `&amp;` in the HTML source code would make a link invalid. It does not. For HTML to be valid, all **data** in it must be HTML-escaped. "Data" means both text (in-between tags) *and* attribute values (like href). When the HTML source is then parsed, the parser will automatically HTML-unescape all data and `&amp;` will become `&` again in the DOM. Do not let the fact that many browsers accept an unescaped ampersand deceive you. It is wrong nevertheless (and FCKEditor just tries to deliver valid HTML).

Comment: What about links where you have a &? Replacing this with &amp; is NOT right.

Comment: @grady: It *absolutely is right*. Read the last paragraph I just added.

Comment: So can I assume that if I look at the page source after the page was created and it still contains &amp; in my links, that as soon as the link is clicked, it will be correct and that the server which the URL points to will "see" the & correctly?

Comment: @grady: Yes. The source code is interpreted by the parser. Interpreting `&amp;` works just the same way as interpreting `&lt;`. If you wrote `&lt;` in your source code, wouldn't you expect that `<` appears on the screen? Now if you write `&amp;`, why wouldn't you expect *the same thing* to happen, i.e. that it becomes `&` before it is used? That is true for href values in just the same way as it is true for any other place in HTML. -- *And no, it does not happen when the link is clicked. It happens when the browser parses your page. Try `onclick="alert(this.href)"` to see what I mean.*

Comment: But the server the URL points to gets the correct URL? I mean, it can parse the parameters correctly?

Comment: @grady: Have you *tried* it? I mean, this should be really simple to find out.

Answer (score 1):

See the custom setting in the fckconfig.js file for FCKeditor.

```
FCKConfig.ForceSimpleAmpersand  = true ;
```

Tomalak is correct about how it should be presented but I'm just pointing out that there is a configuration option in FCKeditor, in case you need to "break the rules". There are situations where this is necessary. Rendering the ampersand as a true HTML entity (&amp;) does not work in some HTML mail clients, which rarely adhere to HTML standards properly anyway. And you may need to force the plain ampersand if you have an additional filter that will convert it to an HTML entity further along your process.